# OJDBC/Oracle registerOutParameter Cursor get Error

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, cursor

I have problem retrieve Cursor from Database.
Database: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0

Database Stored procedure:

```
procedure p_dddw_Client(s_Client in csmweb.web_order_header.client_code_regional%type,
                        s_ClientRole in varchar2,
                        arr_AnyRec in out r_AnyRec);  //TYPE r_AnyRec IS REF CURSOR;
```

Read Stored procedure in Java:

```
    Connection connection = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    try
    {
      connection = createConnection();
      cs = connection.prepareCall("ord_aux.p_dddw_client(?,?,?)");

          //Input parameters
      cs.setString("s_Client", "20975-A");
      cs.setString("s_ClientRole","");
      cs.registerOutParameter("arr_AnyRec",OracleTypes.CURSOR);
      cs.execute(); //ERROR
```

Error code from database in line where is cs.execute():
**ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation**

Does anybody have experience how to do it right or some suggestions?
Did I something wrong?
Thank a lot.

Comment: It may be unrelated, but why do you need an IN OUT parameter, why not just an OUT?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but is the syntax of the prepare call correct?

I think it should be:

```
CallableStatement stmt = 
            conn.prepareCall("{ call ord_aux.p_dddw_client(?,?,?) }");
```

I am also not sure about the calls to setString. I have always addressed the parameters by number, but what you have may be valid too, I am not sure, eg:

```
cs.setString(1, "20975-A");
cs.setString(2,"");
cs.registerOutParameter(3,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```